# Error during sonar runner execution

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I set all properties. but when i run the sonar it shows error.
While it is working with another system which have same configuration.
**The Error is below**

error during sonar runner execution

fail to request server version

Caused by: Status returned by url:'http"//localhost:9000/api/server/version' is invalid :500

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify whether you're using [sonar-runner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Runner) or [Maven](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven) to run your analysis, but this looks like sonar.host.url may have a typo in it. Double-check that it's a valid, fully-formed URL.

EDIT:

For sonar-runner it's set in *[install_directory]/conf/sonar-runner.properties*

For Maven it's set in your *settings.xml* file

Comment: i am using sonar-runner